# Warlock and Hellfire Warlock stacking for Eldritch blast in D&D 3.5

Tags: dnd-3.5e, multi-classing, warlock, prestige-class

The Hellfire Warlock text says:

> At each level, you gain new invocations known, increased damage with eldritch blast, and an increase in invoker level as if you had also gained a level in the warlock class. You do not, however, gain any other benefit a character of that class would have gained.

I have a Rogue 4/ Warlock 8/ Hellfire Warlock 3 so for my eldritch blast damage I consider myself like a Warlock 11 (6d6).

On my next level I plan to take a level of Warlock, but the feature of the 9th of Warlock is just increase of eldritch blast damage.

Do I increase the damage of my eldritch blast again (maybe a little overpowered) or is the 9th level of Warlock in my build lost (no gain)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## You are correct - you would not gain +1d6 Eldritch Blast

As you yourself wrote, you are effectively a Warlock 11 for Eldritch Blast damage, and going up to effectively Warlock 12 does not increase it.

But look on the bright side - your Fortitude and Reflex saves go up by 1!

If you do not think you will get to warlock level 10 (effective level 13), consider multiclassing instead of taking warlock 9. Just as an example, rogue will add damage to your blast if you can catch opponents off-guard, and fighter will let you pick up feats like Weapon Focus (rays). If this is something that interests you, I recommend creating an additional question.

Comment: Seems as though there are much better options than rogue here.

Comment: This is not a question about optimizing the PC. I feel like one example of a well-known, simple, Core class is sufficient for showing the opportunities that multiclassing presents. Feel free to suggest additional ideas.

Comment: Fair enough. Maybe highlight it as such and suggest that better options may be available? Either way, +1.

Comment: It's so sad that Spellwarp Sniper isn't available to Warlocks, it would be *perfect* for a Rogue/Warlock.

Comment: I was under the impression that Weapon Focus (Rays) didn't apply to Eldritch Blast, but that you could instead take Weapon Focus (Eldritch Blast). That would apply to both ranged blasts and melee blasts using Eldritch Glaive.

Comment: @Dyndrilliac "An eldritch blast is a ray with a range of 60 feet." Is there text elsewhere suggesting it can't be Weapon Focused?

Comment: @SPavel It's been a while since I looked over the 3.5 stuff, but I just checked and in Complete Arcane, the text specifically calls out Ability Focus (Eldritch Blast) as an option, which is a similar feat to Weapon Focus. Also, the Touch Spell Specialization feat (which is essentially Weapon Specialization for casters) specifically calls out Weapon Focus (Touch Spells) as a prerequisite. All rays are ranged touch spells, but not all ranged touch spells are rays.